# Specify object type for lodash reduce

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-typings

Lodash [`_.reduce()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#reduce) will accept an object, but I get a TypeScript error (commented below) that suggests it's expecting an array. How do I correctly set the types in this example?

```
interface Fees {
    CardHandlingFee: number;
    AirlineSurcharge: number;
}

const fees: Fees = {
    CardHandlingFee: 2,
    AirlineSurcharge: 3
};

let total = 100;

// Argument of type 'Fees' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NumericDictionary'.
// Index signature is missing in type 'Fees'.
total += _.reduce(fees, (sum: number, v: number) => sum + v, 0);
```

Comment: i dont know typescript, but this code works: total += _.reduce(fees, function(acc, v) {
 return acc + v;
}, 0);
maybe this package can help https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately because you define the type of fees as `Fees`, it is no longer treated an `Object`, which would pass the check of `NumericDictionary<T>` because of [TypeScript's structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

So you have two options basically.

1) Remove the type declaration from the `fees` variable. There is no need for declaring the type anyway. TypeScript will infer the type for you and later when you pass the object somewhere where an instance of `Fees` is needed, it will pass, because of the structural typing (basically duck typing).

```
interface Fees {
    CardHandlingFee: number;
    AirlineSurcharge: number;
}

const fees = {
    CardHandlingFee: 2,
    AirlineSurcharge: 3
};

let total = 100;
total += _.reduce(fees, (sum, v) => sum + v, 0);
```

2) Declare Fees as an extension to `NumericDictionary<number>`

```
interface Fees extends _.NumericDictionary<number> {
    CardHandlingFee: number;
    AirlineSurcharge: number;
}

const fees: Fees = {
    CardHandlingFee: 2,
    AirlineSurcharge: 3
};

let total = 100;    
total += _.reduce(fees, (sum, v) => sum + v, 0);
```

And by the way, you don't need to declare the types of `sum` and `v` in the reduce function, that is infered from the type of `fees`.